# Create textArea elements and copy button with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to create a page containing three elements, one below the other: a text field (TextArea); a Copy button; a div element with empty initial text. And whenever the Copy button is clicked, the text typed in the TextArea should be transferred to the end of the text contained within the div. My code has a textArea, I already managed to put a copy button next to it, but I couldn't think of a function to solve the problem. The idea is that it is solved only with jquery selectors. Finally, above this text box (textarea), the number of characters typed by the user should appear. In my js (jquery), I tried to create a function, but then I deleted it because I couldn't. But I wanted to know how to do this.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.classB').text('Alterado pelo click do botão')
});
```

```html
  <div class="container-fluid p-5 bg-primary text-white text-center">
    <h1>Criando páginas com jQuery</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row div1">
      <div class="col-sm-4 coluna1">
        <p class="classA">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
        //
        <p class="classB"> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris... </p>
        <button id="dados" data-confirm="" data-iddocumento="189738" data-descricao="testte" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs 189738">Clique aqui</button>
        <ul>
          <li>Coffee</li>
          <li>Tea</li>
          <li>Milk</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 coluna2">
        <p class="classC">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
        <p class="classD">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 coluna3">
        <p class="classE">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit...</p>
        <p class="classF">Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris...</p>
        <ul>
          <li>item 1</li>
          <li>item 2</li>
          <li>item 3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row div2">
      <h1>x caracteres</h1>
      <div class="col-12">
        <input class="contar" type="text" value="Vamos contar os caracteres?" /> 
        <button id="copiar" data-confirm="" data-iddocumento="189738" data-descricao="testte" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs 189738">Copiar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row div3">
      <ul>
        <li>C++</li>
        <li>JAVA</li>
        <li>Python</li>
        <li>HTML/CSS</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid rodape"></div>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Related questions with identical code: [How to change text of a paragraph tag on button click with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75238547/943435), [Change the text color of all paragraphs with the click of the button](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75356774/943435)

Comment: Please update the question to include the code that you deleted, even if it does not work.

Comment: $('button').click(function(){
    $('.classB').text('Alterado pelo click do botão') });
    
$(document).ready(function(){
$("textarea").bind("input keyup paste", function (){
var maximo = 100;
var disponivel = maximo - $(this).val().length;
if(disponivel < 0) {
var texto = $(this).val().substr(0, maximo); 
$(this).val(texto);
disponivel = 0;
}
$("#copiar").text(disponivel);
});
});
//but actually, character count should have no limit.

Comment: this is the code that counts how many characters a text has.

Comment: I can't change the code, so I'm sending it here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find the most basic example below (minimal styling, and just the needed elements, to better focus on your issue). You would need to adapt it to your specific code.

The regular expression used with `var txt...` replaces all newline occurrences with `<br>`, so that the copied text retains its original look.

`.trigger('keydown')` was used to simulate the clearing of the `textarea` element and the update of the character counter.

```js
$("#txt").on("keydown",function() {
  var len = $(this).val().length;
  $("#charNum").text(len);
});

$("#btnCopy").on("click",function() {
  var txt = $("#txt").val().replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
  
  $("#result").append(`
    <div class="copy">
      ` + txt + `
    </div>
  `);
  
  $("#btnClear").click();
});

$("#btnClear").on("click", function() {
  $("#txt").val('').trigger("keydown");
});
```

```css
span, button {
  display: inline;
}
.copy {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Character count: </span>
  <span id="charNum">0</span>
</div>
<div>
  <textarea id="txt"></textarea>
</div>
<button id="btnCopy" type="button">Copy</button>
<button id="btnClear" type="button">Clear</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```